# How to name route link?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a problem with adding name to route link.
Below there is screen of routing:
[image]

I want to name last link:

```
GET    /backend/people/:id/vacations/new(.:format)
```

What I tried:

```
resources :vacations, only: [:new, :create] do
  collection do
    get 'new', as: 'people_vacation'
  end
end
```

Unfortunately this code duplicates new action.
[image]

How to avoid this duplication and have only one link(with name) to new action?

Comment: when you use `resources :vacations, only: [:new, :create]` it creates two routes one is for `new` & one is for `create` . And you are trying to add one more route which is already present, so it duplicates the routes. So the solution is remove `:new` from `only: [:new, :create]` then it should be like `only: [:create]` .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you should update your definition to:

```
resources :vacations, only: [:create] do
  collection do
    get 'new', as: 'people_vacation'
  end
end
```

This way, "new" action won't be replicated